# Navigation menu switched per app?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

In Salesforce classic, when we change the app, the tabs change accordingly. In lightning experience, I have noticed however although we can create custom navigation menu, it is delegated to each profile.

Is there something which a user could switch between various navigation menus - e.g. via switching between apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you need is available in the new winter 17 version .

Every app can be a lightning app and there is a clear distinction between a lightning and classic app with ability to add tabs per apps .

Check the below [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xxgpdHZLC4&index=6&list=PLjJeA2SstEtI4salx8v3qfkaX1vmHmILG) to see how this works and also spin a [pre-release org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter17.jsp) to explore further .Also in coming weeks all DE orgs will be updated to winter 17 and you will be able to use the functionality of lightning apps

[image]